# How to do two animations simoultaneously in JQuery?

Tags: jquery, animation

I tried to do two animations in the same moment in JQuery, but I ended up with having the second running before the first.

More precisely, this

```
 animateDotPos();
```

which is written before the one below, is done after

```
$('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('h1[name ='+GetaName[1]+']').offset().top
}, {duration: 1000, queue: false});
```

Can anyone explain me why is this happening??

```js
var current;
var speed = 100;
var canGetPos = true;

$(document).ready(function() {
  var i;
  for (i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
    $('#dot' + i).on('click', function() {
      canGetPos = false;

      animateDotPos();

      var GetaName = $(this).attr('href').split('#');
      $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('h1[name =' + GetaName[1] + ']').offset().top
      }, {
        duration: 1000,
        queue: false
      });

      setTimeout(function() {
        canGetPos = true;
      }, 1000);
    });
  }

  $('.right-box-filler').height($(document).height());

  locateScroll();
  initialDotPos();

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if (canGetPos) {
      animateDotPos(null, speed);
    }
  });
});

function animateDotPos() {
  var dist;
  var previous = current;
  var speedness;

  locateScroll();

  if (previous < current) {

    dist = $('#dotdiv' + current).position().top -
      $('#dotblue').position().top +
      $('#dotdiv1').height();

    speedness = speed * (current - previous);

    $('#dotblue').animate({
      height: dist + "px"
    }, {
      duration: speedness,
      queue: false
    }).show();

    setTimeout(function() {
      $('#dotblue').animate({
        height: $('#dotdiv1').height() + "px"
      }, {
        duration: speedness,
        queue: false
      });

      $('#dotblue').animate({
        top: $('#dotdiv' + current).position().top + "px"
      }, {
        duration: speedness,
        queue: false
      });
    }, speedness);

  } else if (previous > current) {

    dist = $('#dotblue').position().top -
      $('#dotdiv' + current).position().top +
      $('#dotdiv1').height();

    speedness = speed * (previous - current);

    $('#dotblue').animate({
      height: dist + "px"
    }, {
      duration: speedness,
      queue: false
    }).show();

    $('#dotblue').animate({
      top: $('#dotdiv' + current).position().top + "px"
    }, {
      duration: speedness,
      queue: false
    });

    setTimeout(function() {
      $('#dotblue').animate({
        height: $('#dotdiv1').height() + "px"
      }, {
        duration: speedness,
        queue: false
      });
    }, speedness);
  }
}

function locateScroll() {
  var i, temp;
  for (i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
    if (document.documentElement.scrollTop >= $('#t' + i).position().top) {
      temp = i;
    }
  }
  current = temp;
  return temp;
}

function initialDotPos() {
  $('#dotblue').css({
    top: $('#dotdiv' + current).position().top + "px",
    left: $('#dotdiv' + current).position().left + "px",
    collision: 'fit'
  }).show();
}
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";
:root {
  --side-dot: 10px;
}

body {
  font-size: 50px;
}

.page {
  width: 60vw;
}

.right-box {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  float: right;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.right-box-filler {
  float: right;
  width: 35px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.dots-box {
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 30px;
}

.dot-gray {
  float: right;
  margin: 5px;
  width: var(--side-dot);
  height: var(--side-dot);
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0;
  border-radius: var(--side-dot);
  background-color: #C3C3C3;
}

.dot-gray:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dot-blue {
  height: var(--side-dot);
  width: var(--side-dot);
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  float: right;
  margin: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0;
  border-radius: var(--side-dot);
  background-color: #003BF9;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="it">

<head>
  <!-- Some Metas... -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Documento senza titolo</title>

  <!-- CSS -->
  <link href="side-menu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

  <!-- JS -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="scroll.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="right-box-filler"></div>
  <div class="right-box">
    <div class="dots-box">
      <a id="dot1" href="#t1">
        <div id="dotdiv1" class="dot-gray"></div>
      </a>
      <a id="dot2" href="#t2">
        <div id="dotdiv2" class="dot-gray"></div>
      </a>
      <a id="dot3" href="#t3">
        <div id="dotdiv3" class="dot-gray"></div>
      </a>
      <a id="dot4" href="#t4">
        <div id="dotdiv4" class="dot-gray"></div>
      </a>
      <a id="dot5" href="#t5">
        <div id="dotdiv5" class="dot-gray"></div>
      </a>
      <a id="dot6" href="#t6">
        <div id="dotdiv6" class="dot-gray"></div>
      </a>
      <div id="dotblue" class="dot-blue"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <center>
    <div class="page">
      <h1 name="t1" id="t1">Title 1</h1>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisci elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullamco laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur. Duis aute irure
      reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum

      <h1 name="t2" id="t2">Title 2</h1>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisci elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullamco laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur. Duis aute irure
      reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum

      <h1 name="t3" id="t3">Title 3</h1>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisci elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullamco laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur. Duis aute irure
      reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum

      <h1 name="t4" id="t4">Title 4</h1>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisci elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullamco laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur. Duis aute irure
      reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum

      <h1 name="t5" id="t5">Title 5</h1>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisci elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullamco laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur. Duis aute irure
      reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum

      <h1 name="t6" id="t6">Title 6</h1>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisci elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullamco laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur. Duis aute irure
      reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
    </div>
  </center>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I would guss its the duration issue. if the first one have for example 1000 and the next one have 100 then the last one will be triggered first. And then you also have setTimeout which will take extra time

Comment: @Alen. Toma In the function `animateDotPos()` the animations have 300

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this method

refer : https://jsfiddle.net/85mh9wx6/

```
<script>
var current = 1;
var speed = 100;
var previous = 1;
var canGetPos = true;

$(document).ready(function(){
    var i;
    for(i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
        $('#dot' + i).attr("setIndex",i).on('click', function() {
            canGetPos = false;
            previous = current;
      current = $(this).attr("setIndex");

            var GetaName = $(this).attr('href').split('#');
            $('html,body').animate({
                scrollTop: $('h1[name ='+GetaName[1]+']').offset().top
            }, {duration: 1000, queue: false});

            animateDotPos(null, speed);
        });
    }

    $('.right-box-filler').height($(document).height());

    initialDotPos();

});

function animateDotPos() {
    var dist;
    var speedness;


    if(previous < current) {

        dist = $('#dotdiv' + current).position().top
            - $('#dotblue').position().top
            + $('#dotdiv1').height();

        speedness = speed * (current - previous);

        $('#dotblue').animate({
            height:     dist + "px"
        }, {duration: speedness, queue: false}).show();

        setTimeout(function() {
            $('#dotblue').animate({
                height:     $('#dotdiv1').height() + "px"
            }, {duration: speedness, queue: false});

            $('#dotblue').animate({
                top:        $('#dotdiv' + current).position().top + "px"
            }, {duration: speedness, queue: false});
        }, speedness);

    } else if(previous > current) {

        dist = $('#dotblue').position().top
            - $('#dotdiv' + current).position().top
            + $('#dotdiv1').height();

        speedness = speed * (previous - current);

        $('#dotblue').animate({
            height:     dist + "px"
        }, {duration: speedness, queue: false}).show();

        $('#dotblue').animate({
            top:        $('#dotdiv' + current).position().top + "px"
        }, {duration: speedness, queue: false});

        setTimeout(function() {
            $('#dotblue').animate({
                height:     $('#dotdiv1').height() + "px"
            }, {duration: speedness, queue: false});
        }, speedness);
    }
}


function initialDotPos() {
    $('#dotblue').css({
        top:        $('#dotdiv' + current).position().top + "px",
        left:       $('#dotdiv' + current).position().left + "px",
        collision:  'fit'
    }).show();
}
</script>
```

Comment: Please edit the answer to explain what was wrong and how you fixed it.